# How to parse HTML from Play WS response

Tags: java, web-services, playframework-2.0

I have a Play 2.2 application where I am making a WS call and want to parse the HTML that is returned in the response. I want to look for a particular input element and read the value stored in it. The input element only has a name attribute called authenticity_token (no ID). This is the code:

```
final Promise<WS.Response> loginPagePromise = WS.url("https://www.mysite.com/login").get();

        Promise<String> authToken = loginPagePromise.map(
                new Function<WS.Response, String>() {
                    public String apply(WS.Response response) {
                        Document doc = response.asXml();
                        NodeList inputElements = doc.getElementsByTagName("input");
                        for (int i = 0; i < inputElements.getLength(); i++) {
                            System.out.print("Item "+(i+1));
                            Node n = inputElements.item(i);
                            NamedNodeMap m = n.getAttributes();
                            String inputName = m.getNamedItem("name").getTextContent();
                            if (inputName.equals("authenticity_token")) {
                                String token = m.getNamedItem("value").getTextContent();
                                System.out.print("AUTH TOKEN field value: "+ token);
                                return token;
                            }
                        }
                        return "";
                    }
                }
        );
```

I am getting an error on the line Document doc = response.asXml():

```
[Fatal Error] :5:313: Element type "e.length" must be followed by either attribute specifications, ">" or "/>".
```

Surely I'm not the first person to want to do something like this. Any idea why it isn't working?

Answer (score 0):

This isn't a direct answer to your code, but have you thought about using [NekoHTML](http://nekohtml.sourceforge.net/) instead?

It is a java library built to do exactly what you're trying to do, but without all the hassle.